# How to link 2 tables with 1 same column and 1 different column together?

Tags: dax, sql-server-data-tools

I have 2 tables currently and would like to link them together. They currently have 1 same column where they can be joined and 1 of each different column. Would it be possible to join them and leave a null value/0 where there isn't data for the column where they can be joined
Example:

Table 1

| Color | Doors |
| --- | --- |
| Red | 1 |
| Blue | 2 |
| Green | 3 |

Table 2

| Color | Wheels |
| --- | --- |
| Red | 1 |
| Blue | 2 |

What I am looking for is something like this

| Color | Doors | Wheels |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Red | 1 | 1 |
| Blue | 2 | 2 |
| Green | 3 | Null or 0 |

I have tried looking at the union and join functions but gave me errors when trying to combine the tables.

Comment: Where's your code, where's the error message?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.